# Using PHP to find any external devices plugged in

Tags: php

I need a way to find any devices that are currently plugged into a machine using PHP, the web application is ONLY run locally for a business.

I was thinking of maybe checking to see if a folder exists in a directory (for example: E:/DCIM/) and if there is an error the. It wouldn't exist, so check the next one.

Would be nice to get the devices name and storage capability though. I then need to use this information to upload any photos from the DCIM folder.

Comment: You can either use shell commands (shell(), exec()) or search for a PHP library written in C which accesses the OS' native functions.

Comment: Only on Windows? Or all OS?

Comment: You won't be able to test the client side using PHP. It isn't even possible using JavaScript.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: I think he wants to test the devices on the server

Comment: @Reeno But he talks about uploading photo's from a folder, that's something you do on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you running on?

- If using Linux, you could use shell_exec to launch commands, such as "lsusb" to check if the device exists and get info with other linux commands.
- I would expect you're using Windows though...( From the E:).
  I found the following code you could use to help you with your task on http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

  ```
   <?php
  function GetVolumeLabel($drive) {
    // Try to grab the volume name
    if (preg_match('#Volume in drive [a-zA-Z]* is (.*)\n#i', shell_exec('dir '.$drive.':'), $m)) {
      $volname = ' ('.$m[1].')';
    } else {
      $volname = '';
    }
  return $volname;
  }

  print GetVolumeLabel("c");

  ?>
  ```

  Note: The regular expression assumes a english version of Windows is in use. modify it accordingly for a different localized copy of Windows.
  For a specific windows command to get all your required data, I would recommend:

  ```
  wmic logicaldisk get volumename,size,caption
  ```

Overall, it seems you're forcing PHP to do something it isn't meant to do.